# Counter not yet reached for contract

Tags: node, rpc, deploy

I am trying to deploy a smart contract using pytezos and I run into a counter error no matter the RPC node that I use (I have used over 10 nodes by now).

I discussed the error with the pytezos people as I initially thought the error was on their side, but they said that it is a node error.

The error that I am getting is the following (I use pytezos verision 3.11.1

```
pytezos.rpc.node.RpcError: ({'id': 'failure',
  'kind': 'temporary',
  'msg': 'Error while validating injected operation '
         'ooQuoAvGg2R3dNzF6DLzHM4HqWqXZDZ6u5pjHdWQP4wztbFj7u3:\n'
         'Error:\n'
         '  Counter 47334994 not yet reached for contract '
         'tz1YY1LvD6TFH4z74pvxPQXBjAKHE5tB5Q8f (expected 47334993)\n'},)
```

Comment: please post the code that you have that generated this error